# Remove iphone safari's custom "select" tag?

Tags: html, iphone, mobile-safari

I have a simple crossword puzzle app with a list of clues. The clues are in a selector so clicking one will highlight a line on the puzzle. This works fine on PC/Mac but on iPhone it defaults to safari's scrolling select menu that u have to flick to select. So unless you open the scroll menu, u can only see one option in the middle of the big area I made. I'd like my selector to show all its elements like a normal list, which is how it works on non-mobile browsers.

Can I overide Safaris custom select or at least make more of the elements visible before touching the wheel?

Here's what it looks like on PC/Mac

http://mayaincaaztec.com/incacrosswords.html